# What is cat filename1 2> filename2

Tags: file, shell

I got a shell script like this

```
cat file1.dat 2> file2.log
```

Can somebody explain what does mean. I searched a lot but didnt find anything.I have checked this one [cat documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Commands/File_Viewing). But didnt find this `2>`. I am a total newbie in shell script.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2>` is a shell construct. YOu won't find it in the `cat` documentation.

In general (in a shell context), the `>` and `<` chars indicate redirection. The arrows are meant to show the flow, in your case from the first cmd into `file2.txt`. There are also comparison contexts in shell script, so `<` in other cases mean less-than, and `>` greater-than.

In this case `2>` means redirect the std-error output into `file2.txt`

This seems like an odd construct. Note that this code will only capture error messages.
The usual way of getting an error message from `cat` is that the file doesn't exist.

The other issue with this code is that a single `>` indicate "create a new file2.txt" (even if one already exists)

For your purposes, that may be enough. In many cases people want to see a history of activity. It that case you'd want to use the `append` form of redirection, with `2>> file2.txt`.

Would need to know more about the context here to make any further meaningful comment about why this code you've inherited is setup like this.

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

`2>` means redirect file descriptor 2 which is typically stderr.  Whereas without the 2 it is stdout.

Comment: This is general to bash (or whatever shell you use, others may have some different rules), and has nothing to do with cat.  So searching cat documentation couldn't have helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is saying, send the output from `cat file1.dat` that would normally go to `/dev/stderr` to `file2.log`.

Essentially, `cat file1.dat 2> file2.log` sends all of the text printed to STDERR to `file2.log`.

Here are some other examples:

```bash
cat file1.dat 1> file2.log # send STDOUT to file2.log   
cat file1.dat 1>&2 # send STDOUT to STDERR
cat file1.dat &> file2.log # send both STDERR and STDOUT to file2.log
cat file1.dat 2>&1 # send STDERR to STDOUT
```

And, depending on your shell, even more advanced I/O redirections may be supported.

Answer (score 1):

`2>` is shell syntax, so you should look in your shell documentation. It can be used with any command, not just `cat`. It redirects file descriptor 2, which is the standard error stream.

If there are any errors from your `cat` command (`file1.dat` doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to read it, or anything else) then the error message from `cat` will go into `file2.log` instead of to your terminal (or wherever the shell's error stream is originally connected).